# Sending simple data in smart contract call

Tags: smart-contracts

I want to make a simple payment receiver contract not using default the entrypoint that also just sends a plain text message. Is there a way to just send a simple message within the input data that doesn't invoke any functions?

Comment: Who should send the plain text message? To whom should the plain text message be sent? Which smart contract language are you using?